# Python DIGEST-MD5 SASL failures

Tags: python, xmpp, sasl

Implementing Digest-MD5 in Python. Trying to get a basic idea of how it works, so I knocked up some quick code to take a look. It seems to work and seems to be aligned with the RFC but I always just get "Failure" messages. Here is my code:

```
    nonce = [FROM REQUEST]
    username = ***
    password = ***
    server = chat.facebook.com
    cnonce = "X8fwG1eWR+EHEVEB44t5qThEpCn/3KqcftmvSyWS3sN="
    nc = 000000001

    x = "%s:%s:%s" % (self.username, self.server, self.password)

    md5sum = md5.new()

    md5sum.update(x)

    y = (md5sum.digest()).encode('hex')

    a = "%s:%s:%s:" % (y, nonce, cnonce)

    a2 = "AUTHENTICATE:xmpp/%s" % self.server

    md5sum = md5.new()
    md5sum.update(a)
    ha1 = (md5sum.digest()).encode('hex')

    md5sum = md5.new()
    md5sum.update(a2)
    ha2 = (md5sum.digest()).encode('hex')

    kd = "%s:%s:%s:%s:auth:%s" % (ha1, nonce, nc cnonce, ha2)

    md5sum = md5.new()
    md5sum.update(kd)
    z = (md5sum.digest()).encode('hex')

    buffer = "username=\"%s\",realm=\"%s\",nonce=\"%s\",cnonce=\"%s\",nc=%s,qop=auth,digest-uri=\"xmpp/%s\",response=%s,charset=utf-8" % (username, server, nonce, cnonce, nc, server, z)

    send_data = base64.b64encode(buffer)
```

And here is rough outline of the exchange:

```
    Server: <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cmVhbG09ImNoYXQuZmFjZWJvb2suY29tIixub25jZT0iM0E5NjdDQTFFQ0EzM0RDNDdDQzJDQkM0QUQxNjcyMTUiLHFvcD0iYXV0aCIsY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCxhbGdvcml0aG09bWQ1LXNlc3M=</challenge>

    Client: <response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>dXNlcm5hbWU9InRlc3RjaGF0MjUwMiIscmVhbG09ImNoYXQuZmFjZWJvb2suY29tIixub25jZT0iM0E5NjdDQTFFQ0EzM0RDNDdDQzJDQkM0QUQxNjcyMTUiLGNub25jZT0iWDlmd0cxZVdSK0VIRVZFQjQ0dDVxVGhFcENuLzNLcWNmdG12U3lXUzNzTj0iLG5jPTAwMDAwMDAxLHFvcD1hdXRoLGRpZ2VzdC11cmk9InhtcHAvY2hhdC5mYWNlYm9vay5jb20iLHJlc3BvbnNlPTQ0ZTQ3MDkzN2RiZDRlM2E2YTBhY2EwN2IyMDM1YWI3LGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTg=</response>

    Server: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I read the RFC and went through your code line by line. Everything looks good as far as I can tell. Hashing is case sensitive so it is probably something small.

Comment: Please read [RFC 6331](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6331)

Comment: did you figure this out?